# Calculate $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1-\cos \frac{t}{4}}{5-2\cos t}dt$

Tags: definite-integrals

Calculate the following integral:
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1-\cos \frac{t}{4}}{5-2\cos t}dt$$

Any suggestions please? I do not really know where to start!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My method is a little long, that's why I'm not writing the whole thing:

- First as $\cos x=\cos(-x)$
  $$I=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1-\cos \frac{t}{4}}{5-2\cos t}dt=2\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1-\cos \frac{t}{4}}{5-2\cos t}dt$$
- Second, express every term in $u=\cos (t/4)$:
  $$I=8\int_1^{1/\sqrt2}\frac{du}{(16u^4-3-16u^2)\sqrt{u+1}}$$
- Third use $v^2=\sqrt{u+1}$ to get:
  $$I=16\int_{\sqrt2}^{\sqrt{1+1/\sqrt2}}\frac{dv}{16(v^2-1)^4-16(v^2-1)^2-3}$$
- Then use partial fraction(The v looks like u here):
  [image]
- Now you can do the rest, ask if you need help integrating any term above(some of them go to $\ln,\arctan$ or some can be manipulated by something like algebraic twins).

Comment: You have been very brave to attack this monster. I wonder if there is not a problem between $First$ and $Second$ with the change of variable. Numerically, the integral which ends $First$ is $\approx 0.103891$, while the one which ends $Second$ is $\approx 0.584576$. Is there a problem with the first change of variable ? Cheers :-)